# Viber top bar notifications icon missing on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Viber 18.2.0.2

Tags: notification-area, viber

Since Viber 18.2.0.2 there is no top-bar notifications icon available, that was not the case for the prior Viber version (16.1.0.37).

Is that simply gone now?

EDIT: Viber now finally has released a new version (20.3.0.1) and the top-bar notifications icon is working/appearing as expected. This makes this question obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

You can change **viber.desktop** and add **dbus-launch** into Exec line:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Viber
Comment=Viber VoIP and messenger
Exec=dbus-launch /opt/viber/Viber %u
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/viber.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;P2P;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/viber;
```

Install dbus-x11 if needed (for dbus-launch):

```
sudo apt install dbus-x11
```

Comment: Great, finally! Thanks a lot

Comment: now I have the issue that links in Viber would not open. I have Firefox as my default browser and clicking on a link within Viber results in: "Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile." Does something more need to be passed to dbus-launch?

Comment: Hm, strange. Yes looks buggy. Link click working for me (opera) but really slow.
In Viber logs this:
qt.qml.context: qrc:/Resources/QML/Feed/Delegates/TextEditItem.qml:20:5 Parameter "link" is not declared. Injection of parameters into signal handlers is deprecated. Use JavaScript functions with formal parameters instead.
ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.StartServiceByName: object_path= /org/freedesktop/DBus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply...the remote app did not send a reply, the mess bus security policy blocked the reply